# How to run ROS2 without gui from Gazebo?

Tags: google-colaboratory, ros, reinforcement-learning, ros2, gazebo-simu

I want qt reinforce learning training model because gazebo simulator always crashes and turtle model not move when about ten episilon.

I try disable gui is false but not working so I want qt reinforce learning without gui or How to use ROS2 on colab for qt reinforce learning.

Comment: which commands are you using to start gazebo?

Comment: I used "ros2  launch  turtlebot3_gazebo  empty_world.launch.py gui:=false"